# Displaying NFC card data in Binary, Hex, String, etc

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application for reading NFC cards. I came to a point when I needed to design an `abstract` class to streamline the process of creating views for visualizing and editing various forms of data by subclassing the abstract class with views like `BinaryView`, `HexView`, `StringView`, et cetera.

I became aware that I wanted to use what I later discovered is named the "Back Stack", so I wrote up a small "testing" application project in Eclipse. [`developer.android.com`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) kindly provided just what I needed; and after some research I was finally able to discover a reliable way of transmitting data to the child `Activity` during `onCreate`, and lastly a method for the parent `Activity` to accept data from the child `Activity` via all three `finish()` equivalents (the Action Bar "back" button, the previously hardware "back" button, and lastly a custom button within the child activity's view).

The following small files are the result of this morning's adventurous discovery:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tests"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="app_label" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChildActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tests;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_LABEL = "extra";
    private EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        text = new EditText(this);
        text.setText("initial value");
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("call");
        final MainActivity parent = this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity child = new ChildActivity();
                Intent intent = Intents.addStackActivity(parent, child);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LABEL, text.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent, ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL_CODE);
            }
        });
        layout.addView(button);
        layout.addView(text);
        this.setContentView(layout);
    }
    @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL_CODE) {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override public void run() {
                     text.setText(data.getStringExtra(ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL));
                 }
             });
        }
    }
}
```

**Intents.java**

```
package com.example.tests;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class Intents {
    public static Intent addStackActivity(Context parent, Activity activity) {
        int id = 1;

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(parent, activity.getClass());
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(parent);
        // Adds the back stack
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(activity.getClass());
        // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        // Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                parent);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) parent
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
        return resultIntent;
    }
}
```

**ChildActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tests;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ChildActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_LABEL = "mwahahaha";
    public static final int EXTRA_LABEL_CODE = 12345678;
    private EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String data = intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_LABEL);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        text = new EditText(this);
        text.setText(data);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("return");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setTextResult();
                finish();
            }
        });
        layout.addView(button);
        layout.addView(text);
        this.setContentView(layout);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void setTextResult() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL, text.getText().toString());
        this.setResult(ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL_CODE, intent);
    }

    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
        setTextResult();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Before I port this code back into my project, how can it be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Style

You're a little inconsistent about how you're placing your `@Override`s. Sometimes, you place them like this:

> ```
> @Override
> public void foo( ... ) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Other times, you place them like this:

> ```
> @Override public void foo( ... ) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Personally, I'd prefer the top version, but as long as you're being consistent, either style is probably okay.

The code contained in the file `MainActivity.java` suffers from a lack of blank lines, and whitespace in general, which makes it *very* hard to read. I took the liberty of adding a few blank lines, and some whitespace in there, and this was the result:

```
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_LABEL = "extra";
    private EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        text = new EditText(this);
        text.setText("initial value");

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("call");

        final MainActivity parent = this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity child = new ChildActivity();
                Intent intent = Intents.addStackActivity(parent, child);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LABEL, text.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent, ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL_CODE);
            }
        });

        layout.addView(button);
        layout.addView(text);
        this.setContentView(layout);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL_CODE) {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override 
                 public void run() {
                     text.setText(data.getStringExtra(ChildActivity.EXTRA_LABEL));
                 }
             });
        }
    }
}
```

There are more blank lines, but it's overall, much easier to read.

---

## Nitpicks

This line here:

> ```
> int id = 1;
> ```

Should be either of these two things:

1. A constant.
2. A function parameter.

I'd personally go with the function parameter, as it's a pain to go and change a constant variable to a different value each time you need it to have a different value, but if `id` is always going to be equal to `1`, then it should probably just look like this:

```
final int ID = 1;
```

---

*If there's anything else you want me to review, just mention it in the comments, and I'll see what I can do.*